# identifying where to trap php / codeigniter errors

Tags: php, codeigniter, error-handling

I am trying to catch all unexpected error messages in my web app and display a generic message to end users.  But as of right now, I'm getting several php / codeigniter error messages appearing on my page.

I have the following logic in my controller:

```
public function logs()
{
    try {
        $data['logcontents'] = $this->switches_model->get_logs($this->uri->segment(7), $this->uri->segment(4));
        $data['main_content']='logs';
        $this->load->view('includes/template', $data);
    }
    catch (Exception $e) {
        show_error($e->getMessage());
    }   
}// end logs
```

And my model looks like this:

```
public function get_logs($dnsName, $switchname)
{
     try {              
            if ( $switch_obj->connect() )  {
            //do something                  
            return $data;
             }
        else {
            throw new Exception('Connection');

        }//end if
        }// end try
    catch (Exception $e) {
        print 'switches_model get_logs e handler<BR>';
        $this->error_handler($e->getMessage());
        return false;
    }
```

And finally, this is what the error_handler() method in my model looks  like:

```
    private function error_handler($emess)
    {
        switch ($emess)
        {
            case 'Connection':
                $userfriendlyemess = "Unable to connect to device. Please contact administrator! (1)";
                break;

            case 'Empty Data Set':
                $userfriendlyemess = "Device connected.  Unable to get data.  Please contact administrator! (3)";
                break;
            case 'Failure':
                $userfriendlyemess = "Oops!  Unable to complete command. Please contact administrator! (4)";
                break;
            //handling unknown errors   
            default:
                $userfriendlyemess = "Oops!  Something big just happened. (99)";
                log_message('error', $emess); //write to ci logs
                break;
        }
        throw new Exception($userfriendlyemess);            
    }
```

I've tested this logic locally and when i simulate a connection failure, I get one error message that shows the message "Unable to connect to device. Please contact administrator! (1)",which is what I was expecting.

But I'm trying this same logic on a different web server and now, i'm getting a bunch of additional error messages:

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined property: switches::$_password
>
> Filename: core/Model.php
>
> Line Number: 51 A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined property: switches::$_userId
>
> Filename: core/Model.php
>
> Line Number: 51 switches_model get_logs e
>   handler A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Warning
>
> Message: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by
>   (output started at
>   /myapp/system/core/Exceptions.php:185)
>
> Filename: core/Common.php
>
> Line Number: 438 An Error Was Encountered
>
> Unable to connect to device. Please contact administrator! (1)

I'm also wondering what these messages from CI mean... but I can google them.  For now, i'm just wondering how I can prevent these messages from appearing to the user.  I just want them logged. 
In my config.php for CI, I have $config['log_threshold'] = 1;

Thanks.

**EDIT 1**

I figured out why I'm getting the errors- it was because I wasn't properly declaring 2 variables.  But if you could help me sort out to prevent unexpected errors from appearing on the GUI, that'd be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

It may look like those are from CodeIgniter, but they are really from PHP. You probably should read up on PHP error handling in general, but [here is a 50000 ft overview](http://phpcodeignitor.blogspot.com/2011/07/php-error-handling.html) from someone who likes CI. As a rule, you should have error reporting as strict as possible on dev, and on prod it should log to a file (and never be shown to the end user if possible).

Comment: hi there.  I will read that article.  thanks.  having said that, I have done some reading on e handling and have also tried to ensure that my understanding is correct by posting generic questions here.  I'm wondering if someone can point out where in my code example, I'm going wrong